# How to fill bounding boxes in image?

Tags: fill, bounding-box, roi

How to fill region inside bounding box with white and outside with black i? case of one bbx or many bounding boxes for one image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions are:

```
 %%1)roi=[2.262763419483102e+02 2.55 11.593499005964213e+01 8.558429423459245e+01];%% bbBOx format is [ X Y Len Wid ] %% img( X:X+Len-1, Y:Y+Wid-1, : ) = 1; img = zeros(800,800,3); img( roi(1):roi(1)+roi(3)-1, roi(2):roi(2)+roi(4)-1, : ) = 1; imshow(img);

 %%2) img = zeros(500,500,3); img2=insertShape(imgg, 'FilledRectangle', [2.262763419483102e+02 2.55 11.593499005964213e+01 8.558429423459245e+01],'Color', {'white'}, 'Opacity', 1);
```

imshow(img2);